# Why is this PHP if statement non-optimal according to PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm and it says that this if statement is non optimal. Unfortunately it does not say why.

Can anyone tell me it is non-optimal?

```
if ($this->tokens[$next_token_ptr]['code'] === T_ARRAY) {
    $next_token_ptr = $this->tokens[$this->tokens[$next_token_ptr]['parenthesis_opener']]['parenthesis_closer'];
} else if ($this->tokens[$next_token_ptr]['code'] === T_OPEN_SHORT_ARRAY) {
    $next_token_ptr = $this->tokens[$next_token_ptr]['bracket_closer'];
} else {
    // T_CLOSURE.
    $next_token_ptr = $this->tokens[$next_token_ptr]['scope_closer'];
}
```

Comment: Please show what kind of message it shows. I mean -- I want to see a screenshot with the highlighting. I've copy-pasted into empty file and it only complains about unknown variable/constant .. so the context should play the role etc (it seems that this code is part of some loop or something).

Comment: But my guess so far: having it as a `switch` statement might be better / more readable in general (since you are checking the value for the same element).

Comment: It usually says that because splitting the ifs creates easier to read code. The hover/lightbulb message should provide you with the exact reason. However note that the replacement it produces is not always equivalent, especially if you use negatives in your if.

Answer (score 0):

The error was reported from the Php Inspections plugin.

The problem is that this expression is executed twice when it can be done only once

```
$this->tokens[$next_token_ptr]['code']
```

Thanks

Comment: What? Sounds wrong. If it has a value in the first `if`, it has a value in the `else if` too.